# Selector for multiple tags inside a div with id

Tags: jquery

In jQuery, how can I build a selector for tags h1, h2, h3 and p inside #con?

Like `$('#con h1, #con h2, #con h3, #con p')` but without repeating the `#con`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do any of the following:

```
$("#con h1, #con h2, #con h3, #con p")   // your original

$("h1, h2, h3, p", $("#con"))            // pass jQuery object in as context

$("h1, h2, h3, p", "#con")               // pass selector in as context

$("#con").find("h1, h2, h3, p")          // do what jQuery ultimately does 
                                         // in the end when passing context
                                         // as jQuery or as string selector
```

***[I've created a nice little jsFiddle that demos all of this.](http://jsfiddle.net/CodeMaverick/3aE7s/)***

Answer (score 5):

`$('h1, h2, h3, ...', $('#con'))` would work. This sets the context to be #con and searches for h1, h2, etc. inside of the context (#con).