# Combine multiple jQuery events based upon ID's

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 8 tables on a page and four of the have sortable events wired to then such as:

```
       $("#positionTable tbody").sortable({
          ...do stuff
         }).disableSelection();
```

and for visual

```
           $("#positionTable tbody").on("mousedown", "tr", function () {
           if ($('#positionTable').text() == "Done") {
              $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#e1e1e1');
          }
        });
```

and two others.  How can I combine the events into one and then read the one firing the event?  I've tried

```
      $("#positionTable tbody, #degreeTable tbody").sortable({
```

and other combinations but it does not seem to work.  I would love to take these 16 functions and combine them into 4.  I've seen here how to combine for button click with classes but nothing in this area.  I may have missed it and if I did I'm sorry.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205757/selector-for-multiple-tags-inside-a-div-with-id This can help

Comment: Why use ID's and not a class?

Comment: I'm new to this and have always called items by ID's- there maybe a better way with classes and I'm willing to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using relative calls like $(this).parent().  So, regardless of which tbody you select, it will then automatically find the right table and then check that.

```
$(function () {
    $("#positionTable tbody, #degreeTable tbody").sortable().disableSelection();;

    $("#positionTable tbody, #degreeTable tbody").on("mousedown", "tr", function () {
        if ($(this).parent().text() == "Done") {
            $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#e1e1e1');
        }
    });
});
```